# While loop to read different lines from richtextbox

Tags: c#, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to make a simple turtle program where you can type in multiple lines of code to draw on a `PictureBox`. The code is there for the graphics, but I'm struggling with the loops and getting it to read the next line of the string. I know it's going to be something stupidly simple but I've been trying for hours to no avail. I've added the first part of the code cos I'm certain that's where the problem is. I think I've made it way too complicated for myself.

It's reading from a rich text box and I'm trying to read it line by line but split those lines each time. So if something like this is inputted:

`square 50`

`drawto 100,100`

`moveto 200,200`

`square 100`

So far, when the button is clicked, it runs the first line, but I want it to go through each line and perform each action. I know my naming conventions aren't the best

```
private void buttonRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //what happens when run is clicked - main part of code
{
    Console.WriteLine("RUN PROGRAM");
    int lineno = 0;
    string Commandc1 = ProgramCommandWindow.Text.Trim().ToLower();
    StringReader strReader = new StringReader(Commandc1);
    string[] textlines = Commandc1.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);


    while (true)
    {
        textlines[lineno] = strReader.ReadLine(); //reads line of text
        while (textlines[lineno] != null)
        {
            //Commandc1 = strReader.ReadLine();
            string[] Commandc = textlines[lineno].Split(' ', ',');
            while (Commandc[0].Equals("moveto") == true)
            {
                if (!Int32.TryParse(Commandc[+1], out positionx)) ; //translate string to int
                if (!Int32.TryParse(Commandc[+2], out positiony)) ;

                Picturebox.xPos = positionx;
                Picturebox.yPos = positiony;
                //Commandc1 = strReader.ReadLine();
                Refresh();//refresh display
                lineno++;

            }
            while (Commandc[0].Equals("drawto") == true) //what happens if draw line command is used
            {

                if (!Int32.TryParse(Commandc[+1], out positionx)) ; //translate string to int
                if (!Int32.TryParse(Commandc[+2], out positiony)) ;

                Picturebox.toX = positionx;
                Picturebox.toY = positiony;
                MyOutputWindow.DrawLine(Picturebox.toX, Picturebox.toY);
                Console.WriteLine("COMMAND - DRAW LINE");
                //Commandc1 = strReader.ReadLine();
                Refresh();//refresh display

                lineno++;
            }
            while (Commandc[0].Equals("square") == true) //what happens if draw square command is used
            {

                if (!Int32.TryParse(Commandc[+1], out positionshape)) ; //translate string to int 

                Picturebox.sizes = positionshape;
                MyOutputWindow.DrawSquare(Picturebox.sizes);
                Console.WriteLine("COMMAND - DRAW SQUARE");
                //Commandc1 = strReader.ReadLine();
                Refresh();//refresh display

                lineno++;

            }



            break;
        }
        //else while (Commandc1 == "end")
        //{
        //   break;
        //}

        Refresh();//refresh display
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be careful not to  misuse tags. Most tags have descriptions that you can read by hovering over them, and the descriptions usually outline cases where you should or shouldn't use the tags. For example, the `[visual-studio]` question should only be used for questions about the Visual Studio application, as opposed to code authored within the VS environment. I've removed that tag for you.

Comment: Sorry my bad I’m new here

Comment: No worries! I'm just letting you know. :)

Comment: This code does not read from rich text box. No RTB is mentioned in the code.

Comment: the RTB is called ProgramCommandWindow it's in the 5th line down at string Commandc1 = ProgramCommandWindow.Text.Trim().ToLower();